# Uploading pictures with additional data to php

Tags: android

I want to upload a photo from the phone with some data like name and email.

From an Android device I know how to upload a photo and I know how to send data between the phone and the server but how do you do both at the same time?

Should I do them separately?

Comment: have you tried `MultipartEntity`?

Comment: send POST with several data fields

Comment: see post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027882/try-to-upload-the-image-in-php-server-but-it-could-post-in-android/14028071#14028071. May this will give you answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use the MultipartEntity class,

```
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            reqEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(name));
            reqEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody(email));

            if(imagePath.trim().length() != 0) {
                reqEntity.addPart("profilePic", new FileBody(new File(imagePath))); 
            }

            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(urlString);
            HttpEntity resEntity;
            HttpResponse response = null;
            postMethod.setEntity(reqEntity);
            response = hc.execute(postMethod);
            resEntity = response.getEntity();
            response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
```